# Definition of "precision" of an estimator

Tags: estimation

What is the exact definition of *precision* of a statistical estimator? Any references to textbooks are appreciated.

Comment: if precision is 1/Variance, then what's the difference from efficiency?

Answer (score 15):

Precision is typically defined as the reciprocal of the variance of an estimator. A high variance estimator has low precision and vice versa.

Comment: Would it be better to say "the reciprocal" instead of "1 over" to account for precision matrices?

Answer (score 0):

Precision can be defined as 1/variance, or 1/standard deviation. See Wikipedia's article on [Normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Alternative_formulations) (section "Alternative formulations") and references provided therein.